# How can I change date format in WhatsApp on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to use European date format (DD/MM/YYYY) in WhatsApp, but am stuck with the US format (MM/DD/YYYY). All other applications on my iPhone and Mac use European date format, so frustrating.

On searching the Internet, I see that on an Android it is possible to select language English UK to do this. BUT, on an iPhone 7 IOS 15.5, I see only **English**, not **English UK** and **English US**.

Can someone tell me how to change the date format? Thanks.

Comment: My iPhone with Whatsapp is in Switzerland and it is using the European date format, and English only is available.

Comment: Strange, the behaviour you are seeing is what I'd expect, but I'm in Belgium and it insists on US format.